# If a mail arrives in Outlook, start another method (Outlook freezes) Interlop.Outlook C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, outlook

I have the following method part of a WPF app:

```
// This method check Emails
public void CheckForEmails()
{
    Outlook.Application application = null;
    Outlook.NameSpace nameSpace = null;

    if (Process.GetProcessesByName("OUTLOOK").Count() > 0)
    {
        application = Marshal.GetActiveObject("Outlook.Application") as Outlook.Application;
    }
    else
    {
        application = new Outlook.Application();
        nameSpace = application.GetNamespace("MAPI");
        nameSpace.Logon("", "", Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
    }

    nameSpace = application.GetNamespace("MAPI");
    Outlook.MAPIFolder inbox = nameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
    //nameSpace.SendAndReceive(true);

    var items = inbox.Items;
    items.ItemAdd += AnyMethod;
}

//This method execute any method
public void AnyMethod(object Item)
{
    MessageBox.Show("GOOD!");
}

//This is the is the xaml.cs view which initialize the emailAction class if the window is open
public partial class PageView : UserControl
{
    public DownloadDeviceView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new DownloadDeviceViewModel();
        EmailAction emailAction = new EmailAction();
    }
}
```

This method should execute the method `AnyMethod()` when a new e-mail is received in Outlook.

The problem is strangely always different: Sometimes everything works. Sometimes the method does not work at all. And sometimes Outlook freezes and nothing happens again.

Comment: What do you mean with which process? I use Outlook 2016. A Plugin is not an option for me because there is more behinde the code.

Answer (score 1):

You must define the source object at the global scope (class-level) to get the event fired and keep the object alive, i.e. preventing it from being swiped by the garbage collector. For example:

```
Outlook.Items = null;
Outlook.Application application = null;
    Outlook.NameSpace nameSpace = null;

public void CheckForEmails()
{


    if (Process.GetProcessesByName("OUTLOOK").Count() > 0)
    {
        application = Marshal.GetActiveObject("Outlook.Application") as Outlook.Application;
    }
    else
    {
        application = new Outlook.Application();
        nameSpace = application.GetNamespace("MAPI");
        nameSpace.Logon("", "", Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
    }

    nameSpace = application.GetNamespace("MAPI");
    Outlook.MAPIFolder inbox = nameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
    //nameSpace.SendAndReceive(true);

    items = inbox.Items;
    items.ItemAdd += AnyMethod;
}
```

The `ItemAdd` event is not fired when you receive a lot of items at a time (more than sixteen). This is a known limitation of the Outlook object model and exists for decades.

I'd recommend using the `NewMailEx` event of the `Application` class instead. This event fires once for every received item that is processed by Microsoft Outlook. The item can be one of several different item types, for example, `MailItem`, `MeetingItem`, or `SharingItem`. The `EntryIDsCollection` string contains the Entry ID that corresponds to that item.

The NewMailEx event fires when a new message arrives in the Inbox and before client rule processing occurs. You can use the Entry ID returned in the `EntryIDCollection` array to call the [NameSpace.GetItemFromID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getitemfromid) method and process the item.